# How to get caller of a specific constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

I know wrapping with macro can be used for getting caller of a function.  But when it comes to constructors it is not possible as far as I know.  I am not using gcc so backtrace()   function is not an option for me.

Edit:
I am using msvc.

Comment: Do you need this for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes. I am going to use it to detect bugs.

Comment: How about using a debugger?

Comment: I am going to store and use that information when debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An ideal tool for this is a debugger, which doesn't require you to make any modifications to your program.

However, if you really want to get the caller locally within the program, that is also possible - but not in standard C++ without using platform specific or wrapper libraries (Except by modifying the constructor and using the macro trick).

---

> I am not using gcc so backtrace() function is not an option for me.

Then you will need to figure out which compiler you *are* using, and use whatever alternative they provide for stack unwinding.

There is a portable library libunwind which you might use, that works without access to backtrace. It doesn't seem to be ported to windows however.

---

> I know wrapping with macro can be used for getting caller of a function

Wrapping the initialization should work in a similar fashion.

Comment: I have tried wrapping constructor, but it didn't work.

Comment: @wArtist did your attempt differ from wrapping a regular function?

Comment: No, it's not. 
`#define somefunc(x) somefunc(x, __FILE__, __LINE__); #define someClass(x) someClass(x, __FILE__, __LINE__);`
 The second one is not working since someClass is a class name.

Comment: Interestingly, with wrapping, `someClass* a = new someClass(4);` is working. However `vector<someClass*> vec; vec.push_back(new someClass(5));` is not. The second one gives syntax error.

Comment: @wArtist consider what the macro expands to: `vector<someClass*> vec; vec.push_back(someClass(5, __FILE__, __LINE__););`. Notice the semicolon within the argument for `push_back`. That's your syntax error. You can remove the semicolon from the macro. The macro won't work with declaration of variables of type `someClass`, so that's a drawback.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have thought that semicolon on macro is a part of syntax. Removing it solved the problem, thanks. There is no difference left from other "how to get caller of a function" questions. So I am going to solve this question with your answer.